# Calculation in a table with a value from another table

Tags: postgresql

Assumed we have two tables:

Table A:

```
a b c
x 1 null
x 2 null
y 3 null
```

Table B:

```
a b
x 5
y 10
```

I want to update Table A by multiplication of TableA.b with TableB.b and writing it into TableA.c. The value of TableB should be selected by the condition TableA.a = TableB.a. Thus my updated TableA should look like this:

Table A:

```
a b c
x 1 5
x 2 10
y 3 30
```

I thought to do a join of both tables before, but im not sure. What do you think is the easiest and best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres, you can use the `update ... set ... from ... where` syntax.

Consider:

```
update tablea ta
set c = ta.b * tb.b
from tableb tb 
where tb.a = ta.a
```

Comment: i had to change the ta.c to just c in the set line. but it is exactly what im looking for, thx a  lot

Comment: @Pseudalitos: welcome! Sorry about the typo, I fixed it in my answer as well.